# My AS3 Scrollpane doesnt work well in Firefox or Safari

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, scrollpane

Im making a flashbanner for a client. In this banner the viewer should be able to scroll down to see more text. This works ok in Chrome (Can I set scrollspeeds?), but it doesnt work well in firefox nor Safari.

If I scroll lightly, nothing happens, if I give the mousewheel an agressive whirl it scrolls down a liiitle bit...

I tried things like wmode window settings, and using the macmousewheel class, but to no results...

Do you guys have any idea what this could be, it's driving me CRAZY :)

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: This is reason why scrollpane suck. My advice is to write your own sroll event handler and from it change scroll position. If you making just banner it would be easier (and lighter) just to write simple code to do what you exactly want.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem of ScrollPane object. And it's not the only problem of it. As far as I know, you can't avoid it continuing to use ScrollPane. I think you have to download on of custom Scrollbars/Scrollpanes, many of them are freely available.